# Extract common between List<List<string>> and List<string> - C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `List<List<string>> Full`, build up by

```
for(...){
Full.Add(new List<string>());
Full[ListIndex].Add(string1);
Full[ListIndex].Add(string2);
Full[ListIndex].Add(string3);
...
}
```

can be read by

```
string2 = Full[sublistX][element1];
```

A `List<string> Strings` contain some of the instance for `string2`

I want to create a new `List<List<string> NewList` only contain sublist from `Full[sublistX][element1]` which equals to any element in `List<string>Strings`

**For example,**

```
List<List<string>> Full = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() { "11", "AA", "!!", },
    new List<string>() { "22", "BB", "@@", },
    new List<string>() { "33", "CC", "##", },
    new List<string>() { "44", "DD", "$$", },
};

List<string> Strings = new List<string>()
{
    "AA", "DD",
};
```

I want the `List<List<string> NewList` contain:

```
sublist0: "11", "AA", "!!"; //match "AA"
sublist1: "44", "DD", "$$"; //match "DD"
```

**For now, I'm probably doing this in a stupid way (hardcoded)**

```
List<List<string>> Full;
List<string> Strings;
List<List<string>> NewList;

for (int i = 0; i < Full.Count; i++)
{
    if (Strings.Contains(Full[i][4]))
    {
        NewList.Add(new List<string>());
        NewList[ListIndex].Add(Full[i][0]);
        NewList[ListIndex].Add(Full[i][1]);
        NewList[ListIndex].Add(Full[i][2]);
        NewList[ListIndex].Add(Full[i][3]);
        NewList[ListIndex].Add(Full[i][4]);
        NewList[ListIndex].Add(Full[i][5]);
        NewList[ListIndex].Add(Full[i][6]);
        NewList[ListIndex].Add(Full[i][7]);
        NewList[ListIndex].Add(Full[i][8]);
        NewList[ListIndex].Add(Full[i][9]);
        ListIndex++;
    }
}
```

**My question is: is there a better way to do it?**

I think there could be two points that need optimizing:

1. Avoid using `for()` to traverse the whole list "Full," especially when "Full" contains a lot of sublists and "Strings" only have little elements.
2. From the code you can see I now have 10 elements in each sublist, and that could be increased/decreased in the future, but I hard coded the `NewList[ListIndex].Add` from index 0 to 9. Is there a way to get the counts of sublist elements? So that I can use `for(sublist elements count)` to add the NewList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Intersect`...`Any`:

```
List<List<string>> resultList = FullLIst
    .Where(list => strings.Intersect(list).Any())
    .ToList();
```

This performs better than `Contains` if the lists are big.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can utilize Linq as follows :

```
var filteredList = Full.Where(strs => strs.Any(s=> Strings.Contains(s))).ToList();
```

This will give you a list that includes any list that `Full` at least has one element contained by `Strings` list.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pTB5y1)

Comment: I upvoted before testing. I should have tested first. This doesn't work.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for the reminder. I usually add fiddle for testability it seems I was still sleeping while writing this answer.

Comment: Now worries. It works now. FYI, I use LINQPad for testing.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<List<string>> full = ...;
List<string> searchItems = ...;

// only filtering
var result = full.Where(l => searchItems.Any(l.Contains)).ToList();

// also copying
var result = full.Where(l => searchItems.Any(l.Contains)).Select(l => l.ToList()).ToList();

// or faster for big lists
var searchItemsSet = new HashSet<string>(searchItems);
var result = full.Where(list => list.Any(searchItemsSet .Contains)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel that this reads a little nicer:

```
List<List<string>> NewList =
(
    from xs in Full
    where xs.Any(x => Strings.Any(s => x.Contains(s)))
    select xs
).ToList();
```